# Are the "weakly computable" sets precisely the arithmetical sets?

Tags: logic, computability

(By "stream" I mean "a sequence that might be finite.")

Given a Turing machine $T$ and a natural number $n$, write $T_n$ for the stream of $0$'s and $1$'s that appears in the first position of the tape given that the tape starts off with a description of $n$ written on it.

If I understand correctly:

- A set $X \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is said to be *computable* iff there exists a Turing machine $T$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have that $T_n$ is a finite stream, and the last item in this stream is a $1$ if $n \in X$, and it's a zero otherwise.
- As set $X \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is said to be *computably enumerable* iff there exists a Turing machine $T$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $n \in X$ then $T_n$ is a finite stream, and if $n \notin X$ then $T_n$ is an infinite stream.

I'm interested in a generalization of these notions. Define $X \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ to be *weakly computable* iff there exists a Turing machine $T$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $n \in X$ then $T_n$ is eventually equal to $1$, and if $n \in X$, then $T_n$ is eventually equal to $0$.

> **Subquestion.** Do these sets have an accepted name?

So basically, we remove all halting requirements, so that at not point do we know whether or not the $0$ or $1$ we've computed is actually correct. But we require that *eventually* it's correct, even if we don't know whether or not the value we're currently looking at is this eventual stable value.

It's clear that every computably ennumerable set is also weakly computable; just put a $0$ in the first position early on, and change it to a $1$ if you need to. Also, by symmetry, the weakly computable sets are closed under complementation.

> **Question.** I guess it's possible that the "weakly computable" sets are precisely those that are [arithmetical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_set). Is this correct, and if not, is there a nice description of them via universal and existential quantifiers over $\mathbb{N}$ nonetheless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sets are usually called $\mathit{limit\ computable}$, and they have two important characterizations. 1) They are exactly the sets oracle-computable from the Halting problem; and 2) They are exactly the sets at level $\Delta_2$ of the arithmetical hierarchy, i.e., exactly those $X$ which can both be expressed $x \in X \leftrightarrow   \exists y \forall z( \psi(x,y,z))$ and be expressed $x \in X \leftrightarrow  \forall y\exists z( \theta(x,y,z))$ where $\psi$ and $\theta$ do not have unbounded quantifiers.

In particular, the limit computable sets make up only a small part of the arithmetical sets. However, if you define a broader class of sets of all $\mathit{limits\ of\ limit}$-$\mathit{computable}\ T_n$, where the sequence of machines $T_n$ is itself chosen by a Turing machine, this turns out to be the class of $\Delta_3$ sets. And as you might guess, if you keep going, all arithmetical sets can be written this way, as limits of limits of limits$\ldots$of limits.